# How can I delete (with a trick) projects in JEDI VCS?

Tags: delphi, version-control, jedi

I have to split a JEDI VCS server. I have 4 Delphi projects on it, and I have to give 2 projects to a company and 2 to the other company.

The idea is to restore 2 JEDI VCS backups (2 database backups), and remove the projects of the other customer. Now it is not possible to really remove a project from JEDI because of referencial integrity as described in [this article in JEDI VCS FAQ](http://jedivcs.sourceforge.net/jvcsfaq/index.php?action=artikel&cat=15&id=48&artlang=en&highlight=remove).

So since deleting is not possible I had the idea of writing NULL in the blob fields where the source files are kept. In this way if customer 1 tries to restore customer 2 projects he will simply get the file list and then probably an error on reading the files. If I can set NULL to the tables the dpr dfm pas files will not be really there in the db anymore.

Is this possible?
Did anyone wrote a query that does this?

The server version is V 2.4.1.790.

Comment: Do you really have to give them the VCS? If it is for some sort of escrow or just plain "deliverable", I would simply give them the latest version of the source files, not the full vcs history.

Comment: I made the example of 2 customers to explain the problem easily. A scenario closer to the real one is this: company A is developing the application MyApp, but now that will be outsourced to Company B. I would like to give to company B all the backup so there is the history of the changes. Of course latest version is an option, but in this way I lose all the history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A project can be largely removed from a JVCS repo. What can't be removed is the project entry itself, but the modules including their revisions and blobs can be removed.

The steps are:

- delete the project
- call "Server | Deserted Modules" in the main menu of the GUI client
  (this may take some time)
- select all modules (go to the top with the HOME key and press SHIFT and END to select all modules)
- call "Remove from Archive"
  (this may take some time)

BTW, the most recent version is 2.4.5.820.